# Why do I get hot water from the cold side of the faucets

Tags: hot-water

I get steaming hot water downstream of any faucet being used. How can this happen?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We need more information: is this a new occurrence? If so, what changed when it started happening?

Comment: Hi @Bruce. Can You specify (cuz the title leaves a doubt when comparing with the question body) - hot and cold faucets are switched or BOTH are giving hot water? Is hot really >hot< or just not-cold? Other faucets in the house?